# How can I disable some of the routes for resources on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I'd like to define a model as a resource to get all the REST URLs.

But, I'd like to disable some of the generated routes (e.g., DELETE). Is there an easy API for this, or do I just need to declare all the routes individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two ways of doing this

in config/routes.rb

1) as @emm, suggested define only the routes you want

2) use except keyword to `exclude` routes

```
Ex: Excluding destroy action 

resources :books, :except => [:destroy]
```

[read more here](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-except-and-only-routing-options)

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in **routes.rb**:

```
resources :photos, :only => [:index, :show]
```

See more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude specific actions like this:
`resources :articles, except: :destroy`